# Is it possible to allow uesrs to download github artifacts without having a github account

Tags: github, github-actions

Is it possible to allow uesrs to download github artifacts without having a github account?

For instance, we publish installers everytime a commit is merged into master of bitcoin-s, but a common problem users have when attempting to obtain the artifact is they have to login to github. There isn't a clear notification sent to the user that this is a requirement.

I would like to turn off the requirement that user has a github account if possible.

Here is an example:

https://github.com/bitcoin-s/bitcoin-s/actions/runs/1151887204

If you are signed out of your github account, you should not be able to download those artifacts.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a GitHub release with those artifacts.

For example (from the action called [Github Releases](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/github-releases))

```
on: push
name: Build and release on push
jobs:
  release:
    name: Release
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Release
        uses: fnkr/github-action-ghr@v1
        if: startsWith(github.ref, 'refs/tags/')
        env:
          GHR_COMPRESS: xz
          GHR_PATH: build/
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

There are many GitHub actions which could do that. See [marketplace](https://github.com/marketplace?type=actions&query=release+artifact+)

[Example showing that artifacts could be downloaded without login](https://github.com/NuGetPackageExplorer/NuGetPackageExplorer/releases/tag/v5.10.43)